# How to return two multidimetional arrays from same java method?

Tags: java, matrix, return

I would like to know how to return two multidimentional arrays from the same method:

```
public static arraysReturn() {
    int [][] A={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}};
    int [][] B={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}};
    return A,B;
}
```

Comment: A 3D array, with the first dimension as size 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not support returning multiple things at once.

However, you could create a small class that does this:

```
public class TwoArrays {
    public final int[][] A;
    public final int[][] B;
    public TwoArrays(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
    }
}
```

Then make your method like this:

```
public static TwoArrays arraysreturn() {
    int [][] A={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}};
    int [][] B={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}};
    return new TwoArrays(A,B);
}
```

To access values:

```
TwoArrays arrays = arraysreturn();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays.A)); //Due to the way java prints arrays, this is needed, but it isn't a requirement for doing other stuff with the array.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays.B));
```

Comment: if the fields are public I would recommend to set them "final"

Comment: It depends on what needs to be done.  If you wanted to change the value, you could do that.  But I'll label them as final to appease you.

Comment: This is a very good start, I use classes like this with public final variables to group returns quite a bit. The thing is, if you even remotly follow the SRP then those two pieces of data are related and SHOULD be parts of a class.  After this keep an eye out for methods that operate only on this data, they should be methods OF your "TwoArrays" class.  After a while you make the variables private, rename the class and you have done a fantastic proper OO refactor.  This is one of the first steps in really understanding and working towards OO design.

Comment: I am curious to know how to capture the return values in main method? @Pokechu22

Answer (score 5):

Make one array which contains both arrays. In your case

```
int[2][][] = {
    {{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}}, 
    {{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}}
};
```

Or better, make an object which contains both arrays.

Comment: downvote only in that it is a much better idea to add a class, complicating a structure which you have no insight into (from the calling class) is not a good solution.  This works but nobody should ever do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return multiple values from a method.

You can return a single Object that contains two arrays as members though.

You could also return a multi-dimensional array that contains both arrays, but that's not a very OOP solution.